# How refresh a view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have _LayoutOnecs.html file and View Loads with in it renderbody and displays list of records in table. in one of table column i have a Delete icon on click of it goes to controller and deletes record from database once the record is deleted the view should be refreshed so i returned the action to controller which fetches all the records

```
public ActionResult GetAdvertisementDetails()
{
    var advertisementList = new AdvertisementManager().GetAdvertisementDetails();     
    return View("AdvertisementDetails", advertisementList);
}

public ActionResult DeleteAdvertisementDetails(int id)
{
    new AdvertisementManager().DeleteAdvertisementDetails(id);
    return RedirectToAction("GetAdvertisementDetails", "Advertisement");
}
```

once Delete is done it is going to GetAdvertisementcontroller and return view but the Deleted record sits there in table if i Refresh the page by pressing F5 the record is removed from table.
How do i Refresh automatically when the record is deleted

**View Code**

```
<div class="col-md-12 main_table">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="hom_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Advertisement  Name</th>
                 <th>Link</th>
                 <th>Start Date</th>
                 <th>End Date</th>
                 <th width="100">Action</th>
             </tr>
             @foreach (var advertisements in Model)
             {
                 <tr>
                     <td> @advertisements.Description</td>
                     <td> @advertisements.ImageUrl</td>
                     <td> @advertisements.StartDate</td>
                     <td> @advertisements.EndDate</td>
                     <td>
                         <a onclick="EditadvertisementDetails(@advertisements.AdvertisementId)">
                            <i class=" pull_Advt_details tbl_edit_btn fa fa-edit Editbutton"></i>
                         </a>
                         <a id="Deladvertisement" onclick="Deleteadvertisement(@advertisements.AdvertisementId)" >
                             <i class="tbl_del_btn fa fa-trash"></i>
                         </a>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             }
         </table>
     </div>
     <!-- Responsive main table Ends -->
</div>
```

Comment: Provide implementation of GetAdvertisementDetails() as well as View code.

Comment: You last (now deleted) question indicated you were using ajax to call this method - is that still the case?

Comment: I am using ajax to call delete methode like this..function Deleteadvertisement(AdvertisementId) {
    GetServerData('Advertisement/DeleteAdvertisementDetails/' + AdvertisementId, null, null);
      
}

Comment: dont use ajax call make simple call either by jquery or javascript

Comment: So why did you delete the last question? Ajax calls stay on the same page they do NOT redirect so `return RedirectToAction(...)` is pointless. Why would you degrade performance by redirect anyway instead of just removing the relevant `advertisement`from the view. If you do want poor performance then do a normal submit (include a form element and submit button for each advertisement)

Comment: i tried like this<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteAdvertisementDetails", "Advertisement", new { id = @ViewBag.LoginUser.MerchantId })</a>" but  it is returning to blank page so i used ajax

Comment: Do you want to redirect or do you want to stay on the same page and just remove the `Advertisement` from the view and avoid the unnecessary overhead of reconstructing the view all over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax calls stay on the same page. Your use of `return RedirectToAction("GetAdvertisementDetails", "Advertisement");` in the controller method is ignored. Its also unnecessary to redirect since you can just remove the row from the table

Modify the html to (note remove the `id` attribute which is generating invalid html):

```
<a class="delete" data-id="@advertisements.AdvertisementId>
  <i class="tbl_del_btn fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

and use the following script to call the controller method and remove the row

```
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteAdvertisementDetails", "Advertisement")';
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  $.post(url, { id: $(this).data('id') }, function(response) {
    if(response) {
      row.remove();
    }
  }).fail(function (response) {
    // display error message?
  });
});
```

and modify the controller to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteAdvertisementDetails(int id)
{
    new AdvertisementManager().DeleteAdvertisementDetails(id);
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in console i am getting error http://localhost/Membership/Advertisement/@Url.Action(%22DeleteAdvertisementDetails%22,%20%22Advertisement%22) @Stephen Muecke

Comment: What error are you getting? (and whats "Membership"? - are you using areas?)

Comment: http://localhost/Membership/Advertisement/@Url.Action(%22DeleteAdvertisementDetails%22,%20%22Advertisement%22) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Again, what is "Membership"? Are you using areas? (404 means the method is not found so you need to specify the correct - I have only based it on what you have provided in your question)

Comment: Membership is name of the solution for other controllers i am getting url
http://localhost/Membership/Advertisement/GetAdvertisementDetails but for this the url is http://localhost/Membership/Advertisement/@Url.Action(%22DeleteAdvertisementDetails%22,%20%22Advertisement%22)
if url is http://localhost/Membership/Advertisement/DeleteAdvertisementDetails it will go to the controller

Comment: Then type that url into the address bar. Does it hit the controller? If not then you need to adjust the url i.e. `var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteAdvertisementDetails", "Advertisement")';` needs to be something else, maybe you need to specify the area but you have not given enough information to know.

Comment: Thank you very much I have changed my url to 
var url = "DeleteAdvertisementDetails";(Name of the controller action) and it is hitting the controller @Stephen Muecke